# Folder created inside Internal Storage not showing up

Tags: android, android-file

I am trying to create a folder inside Internal Storage on Button click, but I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
backUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        File sub = new File(MainActivity.this.getFilesDir(), "new_folder");
        if (!sub.exists()){
            sub.mkdirs();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sucess!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Looks alright, displays the sucess toast but can't see the folder in directory. Even tried refreshing the Directory with:

```
  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this, new String[] {sub.toString()}, null, null);
```

Also provided WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Menifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: are you setting the right in your manifest to write to internal storage?

Comment: @K.Dexter yes. i forgot to mention in question but I've also given WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission